# Problem getting Date from Cloud Firebase Server

Tags: android, date, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the date from the Cloud Firebase server, but I get the following error in a toast that I have designated for the addOnFailureListener:

```
com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFuctions.Exception: INTERNAL
```

I am going to attach the code that I have added in the app, so that they can check it and guide me and see if they find the problem, in advance Thank you

------------ Index.js -----------------------

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.getTime = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
admin.FieldValue.firestore.Timestamp.now();
});
```

---

and here is the code with which I receive the date in the MainActivity:

------------- MainActivity.java -------------------------

```
FirebaseFunctions.getInstance().getHttpsCallable("getTime")
                            .call()
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<HttpsCallableResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(HttpsCallableResult httpsCallableResult) {
                                    Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp) httpsCallableResult.getData();
                                    System.out.println("Result: "+ timestamp);
                                    Toast.makeText(Campeonatos.this, "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(Campeonatos.this, "NO " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

---

The Toast of the addOnFailureListener is the one that marks the error, I hope you can help me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this:

> Example

```
var sessionsRef = firebase.database().ref("sessions");
sessionsRef.push({
  startedAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
});
```

According to the documentation  [`firebase. database. ServerValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue).